# Maven says missing plugins: how to install them?

Tags: android, soap, maven, maven-plugin, maven-3

I've got some problems using Maven on this ready-to-use project: http://wiki.javaforum.hu/display/ANDROIDSOAP/Home
Basically, I just need to change a couple of rows and I should be ready to use the generated files. The problem is that when I do mvn:idea (or mvn:eclipse) clean, I get these warnings:

```
Z:\Workspace\AndroidSOAP>mvn idea:clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for hu.javaforum.android:AndroidSOAP:pom:0.0.4-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin is     missing. @ line 117, column 15
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 95, column 15
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-report-plugin is missing. @ line 167, column 15
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin is missing. @ line 156, column 15
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 106, column 15
```

How can I install the missing plugins? I've been searching and come out empty-handed.

Comment: Epic: The one thing MacGyver can't fix: `Maven`

Comment: Any ideas? I really can't find any solution.

Comment: Related: [Maven 3 warnings about build.plugins.plugin.version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123044/maven-3-warnings-about-build-plugins-plugin-version)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you using Maven3? Maven3 recommends to specify a version for every plugin in the pom.xml, otherwise a warning is shown. I had a look at the pom at http://svn.javaforum.hu/svn/android/AndroidSOAP/trunk/AndroidSOAP/pom.xml the plugins are already there, but the version numbers for the plugins seems to be missing indeed. The warnings shouldn't appear with Maven2, as this is more tolerant to sloppy poms. A nicer explanation is here: https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-AutomaticPluginVersionResolution

You can find the version numbers of the latest release version for each plugin at every public maven repo e.g. at http://search.maven.org/

Comment: The warnings have gone away.
A more detailed message by Maven would have been great...
Thank you very much!