# Creating maven job on hudson issue

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, maven-3

I am learning Hudson. I tried to set up a "Maven3 project" in Hudson 3.0.1 deployed in Tomcat 7 and when I try get "clean install" executed. First I saw following warning:

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for     DummyProject :DummyProject :war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 46, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
```

I had this plugin in the POM. I don't know why this warning is coming. 
This warning was followed by following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building DummyProject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/mojo/tomcat-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/mojo/tomcat-maven-    plugin/maven-metadata.xml (439 B at 2.1 KB/sec)
projectFailed DummyProject :DummyProject :0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[HUDSON] Archiving C:\tomcat7\webapps\hudson-3.0.1\jobs\DummyProject\workspace\pom.xml to C:\tomcat7\webapps\hudson-3.0.1\jobs\DummyProject \modules\DummyProject $DummyProject \builds\2013-    06-27_10-58-26\archive\DummyProject \DummyProject \0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\pom.xml
sessionEnded
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.234s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 27 10:58:29 PDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException: Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean.
 [DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: DummyProject #2 due to result: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anyone let me know what is wrong here? I will appreciate if somebody will refer some documents which shows maven job creation on Hudson too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin is missing

Simply add plugin version in order to get rid of warning. Here's [comprehensive "tutorial"](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-3-need-to-know-the-plugin-version/) and [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123044/maven-3-warnings-about-build-plugins-plugin-version?lq=1).

> > Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal

Make sure that your goals are `clean install` and not `mvn clean install`. 
`mvn` is indeed not *a valid lifecycle phase or a **goal***.

You may take a look at [chapter 7 of the hudson book](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.chunked/ch07.html). It demonstrates `clean install` as an example.

Comment: Thanks lifus for your reply. You were absolutely right for the warning. For Others Information, the Error was coming because project was not getting set properly. After I followed the steps given in the referenced book. it worked well.