# Scope of pluginManagement in Maven & reporting.plugins.plugin.version missing warning

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jacoco-maven-plugin

My Maven project gives me reporting.plugins.plugin.version warnings like these:

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example:test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 10, column 21
```

I'm aware that Maven 3 [is stricter about plugin versions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4123044/2032064) and that plugin version must be specified. I specified the version in pluginManagement:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

This works fine and without warnings when I use plugin in `build/plugins`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It **doesn't work**, however, in `reporting/plugins`:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

**My questions are:** Is the scope of version specified in `build/plugingManagement` limited only to within the `<build>` tag? Can I fix the warning without duplicating the plugin version at two places?

---

Here is a full example generating the warning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </reporting>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in older maven versions. Have a look at [this bug ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSITE-443) at apache.

. Try using Maven 3 and maven-site-plugin-3.

Comment: Right, I was using Maven 3.0.5, the bug was fixed in 3.1.0 according to the bug ticket. Thanks!